# How Fail-fast Iterator works internally?

Tags: java, collections, fail-fast

I know what is a fail-fast and fail-safe iterator. 
Fail-Fast iterators immediately throw ConcurrentModificationException if there is a structural modification of the collection.

Fail-Safe doesn't throw any exception as they work on a clone of collection.

My question is how does a fail-fast iterator come to know that a modification is made to my collection?

Comment: I would like to encourage you to write a small method and try to implement  a behavior so that it will throw exception on some predefined conditions. Or As soon as the condition meet method should stop executing and throw exception.

Comment: @madhepurian Thanks for idea, will definetly try it :)

Comment: "how? " there is an `int` counter that is incremented by each method that does a *structural* modification. Each relevant iterator operation checks this value against the value of the counter stored when the iterator is created. See documentation of `AbstractList` field [modCount](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount) (or its source code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the implementation yourself.

Let's consider `ArrayList` as an example.

It has an inner `Itr` class, which the `iterator()` method returns an instance of.

The `Itr` class has an `expectedModCount` counter, which is initialized with the enclosing `ArrayList`'s `modCount`:

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;
    ...
}
```

When you call methods of the `Iterator`, such as `next()` or `remove()`, it calls the `checkForComodification()` method:

```
    final void checkForComodification() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
```

which throws an exception if the `ArrayList`'s `modCount` has incremented since the `Iterator` instance was created.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single way to implement this.

In the case of `ArrayList` (and other classes in `java.util`), the iterator keeps an [`int expectedModCount`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l828) ("expected modification count"), which it compares to the `AbstractList`'s [`int modCount`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l601) ("modification count"), which gets updated whenever there is a structural modification to the list; the iterator throws an exception if the two values are different.